# How to set date column as index when using anomalize library in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to run anomaly detection on Twitter time series data using the anomalize library. I've tried everything I can think of but keep getting the same error when I try to run this code:

```
combined_anom <- count_combined2 %>%
  time_decompose(count) %>%
  anomalize(remainder, alpha = 0.05, max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
  time_recompose() %>%
  plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE) +
  ggtitle("Combined Brexit Dataset Anomalized")
```

```
Error in try.xts(x, error = "'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible") : 
  'x' needs to be timeBased or xtsible
```

Here is a sample of the dataset:

```
# A tibble: 3,770 x 3
# Groups:   keyword [4]
   date       keyword   frequency
   <date>     <chr>         <int>
 1 2016-06-01 brexiteer        88
 2 2016-06-02 brexiteer        78
 3 2016-06-03 brexiteer        70
 4 2016-06-04 brexiteer        78
 5 2016-06-05 brexiteer        74
```

I think I need to set the date column as the index, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I tried assigning it when reading in the csv, but that didn't work.

I'm totally stuck. Can anyone help?